# Rails - Comment Threading using Nested Sets? But Which Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm interested in adding comment threading to my app. It seems like a nested set gem is the way to go. What I can't tell is which gem is the way to go, most popular, etc... Most of the nested_set, awesome_nested_set, appear to not have been updated in some time.

Given that I want comment threading. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Railscasts [196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2). IMO, the reason the gems tend to go unmaintained is because it's ridiculously easy to do with two helpers and two javascript methods. I don't want to encourage your to build the wheel yourself, but keep in mind that it isn't a very difficult wheel.

Don't like idea? Fork [the repo](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) and use your own. You shouldn't blindly be using open source without a little bit of exploration of how it works anyway.

Comment: Thanks this is part of my exploration :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I think you were on the right track by looking into nested sets for your comment threads.  In fact, there is a new Railscast ([262](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry)) about this very thing that uses the Ancestry gem for nested sets.